# With MySQL, how do I update a column which is a reserved key? 

Tags: mysql, sql

if I were doing it:

```
update p set te = concat('Ez itt a(z) ',xxxx,' tájtl');
```

it would work OK, but xxxx is "key" now, so:

```
update p set te= concat('Ez itt a(z) ',key,' tájtl');
```

so I cant do that. How to fix it? Renaming that column is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you have to put the column name in backticks ( ` symbols )

```
update p set te = concat('Ez itt a(z) ', `key`, ' tájtl');
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, every reserved word must be eclosed in backticks:

```
UPDATE p SET te = CONCAT('Ez itt a(z) ', `key`, ' tájtl');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update p set te= concat('Ez itt a(z) ',`key`,' tájtl');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update p set te= concat('Ez itt a(z) ', `table_name`.`key`,' tájtl');
```